# Redirecting to another page in confirm box

Tags: javascript, html

What should I do if I want to send someone to another page (using antoher link) after clicking "ok"? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type = text/javascript>

var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
if (result == true) {
//Here somehow I should put the link
}

 else {}

<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `window.location.href`

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the `location.href` to set the new **url** for redirection.

```
var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
if (result == true) {
 window.location.href="http://yourwebsite.com/yourpage";
}

 else {
 // code the else part.
}

<script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.